# Dynamically generated closure

Tags: groovy, closures, groovyws

Dynamically  generated closure

I've written soap request in groovy wslite :

```
def request = {
        envelopeAttributes('xmlns:art': 'http://url')
        body {
            'art:validate' {
                item(itemValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

It's working fine, but now I have to change this to list, so at the end it will be something like that:

```
def request = {
        envelopeAttributes('xmlns:art': 'http://url')
        body {
            'art:validate' {
                item(itemValue)
            item(itemValue2)
            item(itemValue3)
            }
        }
    }
```

But have know Idea how I can dynamically create this request from List. I've even extracted this to variable:

```
def items = {
                item(itemValue)
            item(itemValue2)
            item(itemValue3)
}
```

but I don't know how to add new items to this closure. Is there any easy way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your given `items` Closure, this may work:

```
def request = {
    envelopeAttributes('xmlns:art': 'http://url')
    body {
        'art:validate' {
            items.delegate = delegate
            items()
        }
    }
}
```

if you need other things inside `art:validate`

Answer (score 3):

Builder closures are normal Groovy code, so something like

```
def values = [itemValue, itemValue2, itemValue3]
def request = {
    envelopeAttributes('xmlns:art': 'http://url')
    body {
        'art:validate' {
            values.each { item(it) }
        }
    }
}
```

should work fine.  Or if you have

```
def items = {
        item(itemValue)
        item(itemValue2)
        item(itemValue3)
}
```

then you can do

```
def request = {
    envelopeAttributes('xmlns:art': 'http://url')
    body {
        'art:validate'(items)
    }
}
```

(passing the existing closure to `art:validate` rather than defining a new one inline).

Comment: Nice call passing the closure to `art:validate` :-)